# Matlab - combining two surface plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to combine two surface plots in a single figure. The problem is that one of the two is plotted on the wrong axis. The reason is that:

surface1 = surf(x,y,z)
surface2 = surf(x,**z,y**)

This is due to the mathematical equations behind x,z and y. I can't change them, i.e. rearrange z in terms of y for surface2.

Is there a way to map the two to the correct axes?

Comment: Matlab doesn't care about your mathematical equation. It just takes the first input of surf as the direction along the "x" axis, the second along the "y" axis and the third along the "z" axis. So as long as the dimensions of the input arrays are consistent, you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you show the code you briefly mention in the question, readers may have a chance to reproduce the problem.